# polymer paper-input-decorator horizontal layout

Tags: css, polymer

I am looking to have an input field decorated with paper-input-decorator aligned horizontally with other elements. Does anyone know how to style paper-input-decorator to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With more research I found i could use the layout facilities of Polymer to achieve this. I wrapped all the elements I wanted horizontally aligned in a div with the attributes layout and horizontal as so:

```
<div layout horizontal>
...elements you want aligned horizontally
</div>
```

For more on the layout facilities of Polymer see https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html